# Animated character exported to THREE.js not animating properly

Tags: animation, export, bones, three.js

I am trying to export animated character from Blender to THREE.js JSON using official THREE.js blender exporter. I have tried a few models from the internet and also a model included in THREE.js: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/models/skinned/marine/marine_anims_core.blend

Exported JSONs are tested in this example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_blending.html

Imported models are animating badly + model has a wrong x rotation (-90deg). The rotation can be repaired by rotating imported object in THREE.js. However it rotates the bones too and so not fix the problem. I think the problem is bad rotation of skeleton in relation to the model.

How should I export the model from blender correctly? Or is there a way to fix this later in javascript?

Blender: 2.73, 2.79, THREE.js: r77, r88, Chrome

Example: [Wrong animation video](https://youtu.be/cmx1ZsP2UcQ)

[image: Wrong animation.]
[image: Exporter settings.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GitHub there are a [number of open issues](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Blender+Exporter%22) about incorrect transforms and animation with the three.js JSON exporter. This is very likely one of those problems... I would try checking there, or exporting to FBX or [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/) in the meantime.